Report Builder Layout
I am trying to create a report in report builder.
The data and the target layout are as follows:

I create a table with 1 row and 2 columns. In the second column I added a matrix. So the yellow part is a table cell and grouped by Region and the rest are in a matrix.
I have a Country - Branch concatenated column.  So orange is a Row Group by Country - Branch.
Green is a parent Column Group and Blue is a child Column Group.
Problem:
I have almost achieved what I want except grouping by Parent Type - 1 and Parent Type -2 are not working.
For C1 I have a header Parent Type -1 and C2 also has a header Parent Type -1 i.e. C1 and C2 are not grouped under 1 header.

post some sample data as it is returned from your dataset query, explain how it should be aggregated and show the expected results and what you are seeing now. It's difficult to understand without seeing some data. Also include any grouping expression for row and column groups that you have in place.

@AlanSchofield I have posted data and some illustration of the target layout.

@AlanSchofield Added data and grouping
